# While loop in Jython random module

Tags: jython, jython-2.5

How can I include a while loop to keep the user guessing until they get the right answer in the following Jython program?

```
import random

def numberGuess():
    printNow("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10")
    guess = 0 
    randNum = random.randrange(1,11) 
    guess  = int(input("Try to guess the number: ")) 
    if guess > 10:
        print("Wrong! You guessed too high")
    elif guess < 1:
        print("Wrong! You guessed too low")
    else :
        print(" you got it")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

while True:
    print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10")
    randNum = random.randrange(1, 11)
    guess = int(input("Try to guess the number: "))
    if guess == randNum:
        print("You got it")
        break
    else:
        if guess > 10:
            print("Wrong! You guessed too high")
        elif guess < 1:
            print("Wrong! You guessed too low")
```

Comment: its not doing anything and not showing any error either.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the reason that was happening was because everything should be within the `while` loop.

Comment: ======= Loading Progam =======
Try to guess the number: -3
Try to guess the number: